# Build multiple maven pom files and log in to a single file

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee

I am working on a Java project. In my project multiple dependency projects are these. So I created a bat file to build all projects one by one. Please see the logic I used to achieve this.

```
set x=proj1-prx
set y=proj2-prx
set z=proj3-prx

set LIST=(%x% %y% %z% )

echo Checkout and deploy started
for %%G in %LIST% do (
set _module=%%G
set  _value=!%%G!
echo Checkout module - %%G
svn checkout %SVNHOST%/%%G/%REPO% %WORKSPACE%\%%G\%REPO% --username %USER% --password %PASSWORD%
echo Install module to AEM - %%G
mvn clean install -Dskiptests  -f %WORKSPACE%\%%G\%REPO%\pom.xml -l output.log
@ECHO OFF
)
echo Checkout and deploy finished
```

This file is executing well , Log file also creating but each time for loop building a project the build result overrides in to log file. I want build result of all project. Please help me friends

Comment: why don't you simply build a "master POM" mentioning the others as Modules?

Comment: The project is designed like that. I am not in the position to make changes in the pom files .

Comment: *"I am not in the position to make changes in the pom files"* - You don't need to *change* and existing POM, just create a new one on your own PC. you don't even need to check it in to your SCM.

Comment: I just want to keep build details in log file. It is happening now but log file is being overwritten. I would like to fix this issue instead of creating new pom and every dependency detail. Actually more than one main project is there so creating new POM is difficult

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want build result of all project. Please help me friends

You cannot depend on mavens logger implementation. Use the OS stdout/stderr redirection:

at the beginning of your batch file delete the old log content:

```
echo > output.log
```

then change the maven call:

```
mvn clean install -Dskiptests  -f %WORKSPACE%\%%G\%REPO%\pom.xml >> output.log 2>&1
```

Comment: Thanks.. my bat file starts with @ ECHO OFF . DO I need to change that in to echo > output.log?.. In for loop you can see @ECHO OFF as last sentence, that also be changed in to echo > output.log??

Comment: *"DO I need to change that in to echo > output.log?"* No, `echo > output.log` must be a *new entry* in your batch.